# Highcharts sankey diagram error when looping

Tags: highcharts

I want to build a sankey diagram with some looping items.
I found this JSFiddle example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
        marginLeft: 100,
        marginBottom: 200,
        marginRight:200
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
    },

    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['a', 'b', 5 ],
            ['b', 'c', 5 ],
            ['c', 'b', 5 ],
        ],
          clip: false,
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Sankey demo series'
    }]

});
```

It works, but some modifications of the series give errors.
For example this data guides to

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

error in console:

```
        ['a', 'b', 5 ],
        ['b', 'c', 5 ],
        ['c', 'a', 5 ],
```

So is there any possibility to loop it back to the first element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, circular references are not supported in sankey diagrams in highcharts. See the open issue at github for more details: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8218.